Djano form no populating with user instance
I'm very new to Django, and I am working on my very first project. I am trying get a model form to populate with the user instance. I have been struggling to find out when when I load the form it doesn't populate with the user instance. The form also doesn't update my model.
Here is the model:
class Income(models.Model):

    class Type(models.TextChoices):
        SALARY = 'Sal', 'Salary'
        VARIABLE = 'Var', 'Variable'
    
    class PayFrequency(models.TextChoices):
        MONTHLY = 'MON', 'Monthly'
        BIWEEKLY = 'BW', 'Bi-weekly'
        SEMIMONTHLY = 'SM', 'Semimonthly'
        WEEKLY = 'W', 'Weekly'
        ANNUAL = 'AN', 'Annually'

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    pay_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=Type.choices)
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PayFrequency.choices)
    #Need day of the month, to calculate weekly, bi-weekly and monthly pay days
    pay_date_one = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(31), MinValueValidator(1)]
     )
    #Need second date to calculate semi monthly(2x a month, so need both dates)
    pay_date_two = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(28), MinValueValidator(1)], null=True, blank=True
     )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} Income"

Here is view:
@login_required()
def income(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = IncomeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()

    else:
        form = IncomeForm(instance=request.user)        
    return render(request, 'home/income.html', {
        "form": form
    })

Here is the template:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %} Income {% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Income</h1>

    <div>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <button>Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>


{% endblock content %}

Any ideas of why this form isn't populating or updating when hitting save? I have a very similar model and form that is working as expected and I don't notice anything different.
I have been trying to update the form to find out why isn't not updating the model or populating when I load the form.
